# How do I restart pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

I'm using Ubuntu. I can't see any data and stuck on loading when pgAdmin window is idle for a while. How to restart pgAdmin in Ubuntu?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed, and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
pkill pgadmin
```

Or detect your specific process PID (first number) with:

```
ps aux | grep pgadmin
```

Then run:

```
kill <PID NUMBER>
```